# How to get url query parameters in Clack, Lucerne or Caveman?

Tags: common-lisp

How can we access the url's query parameters in a Clack environment ?

It looks like they are in a clack `*request*` object, named `query-string`, but I don't know how to access them: clack [is not documented](http://quickdocs.org/clack/) and [this doc](https://jasom.github.io/clack-tutorial/pages/getting-started-with-clack/) isn't clear on that.

BTW, how to explore the `*request*` in slime's debugger, while I'm on a break for instance ? it only prints as "CLACK:REQUEST".

I see nothing in Lucerne's [doc](http://eudoxia.me/lucerne/docs/overview.html) or code, and it's a shame because I like its `with-params` macro.

**update**: don't search more, this macro works very well !

Caveman [has something](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman#structured-querypost-parameters) but the common case isn't that clear to me (some find like me it is [a bit cumbersome](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman/issues/22) (and I'm trying out Lucerne)).

Comment: There seems to be a generic function `QUERY-PARAMETER` in [clack.request](http://quickdocs.org/clack/api#package-CLACK.REQUEST). I haven't used clack or tried it, but it seems like it should work. You should be able to inspect the object with [slime inspector](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Inspector.html#Inspector).

Comment: thanks for the links they helped. (I got it and give details below the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ningle, I can do `(lack.request:request-query-parameters ningle:*request*)` to get association list with all query parameters. May be it will work for you.

To inspect request in a frame, just hit "i" when cursor on a frame and enter something like `ningle:*request*`. I see the request like that:

```
#<LACK.REQUEST:REQUEST {100B2EDB73}>
--------------------
The object is a STRUCTURE-OBJECT of type LACK.REQUEST:REQUEST.
ENV: (:RAW-BODY #<FLEXI-STREAMS::VECTOR-INPUT-STREAM {100B2ED2D3}> :REQUEST-METHOD :GET :SCRIPT-NAME "" :SERVER-NAME "ws-dashb$
METHOD: :GET
SCRIPT-NAME: ""
PATH-INFO: "/some-path"
```

And can dive into each slot's value.

Probably it depends on optimization declarations. If does not work, try to enter `(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))` before loading your application.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. It was similar for me. I didn't have `lack.request` but `clack.request` and the `*requert*` object was given by lucerne: `(clack.request:query-parameter lucerne:*request*)`

Comment: so as in Ningle doc, to access a given query parameter: `(assoc "the-query-param" (clack.request:query-parameter lucerne:*request*) :test 'string=)`. I hope one framework will provide an helper, like Lucerne's `with-params`…